# How do I make random number in this css string (laravel)

Tags: php, css, laravel

I want to add a random number from 1000 to 9999 on the css "10000ms" line.

```
    if(data.type == 'slider') {
        $('.wheel-game .time').hide();

        $('.wheel-game .wheel-img').css({
            transition: '-webkit-transform 10000ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.64, 0.45, 1)',
            transform: 'rotate('+data.slider.rotate+'deg)'
```

the code is in laravel help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

And use it like this

```
  if(data.type == 'slider') {
        $('.wheel-game .time').hide();

        $('.wheel-game .wheel-img').css({
            transition: '-webkit-transform ' + getRandom(1000, 9999) + 'ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.64, 0.45, 1)',
            transform: 'rotate('+data.slider.rotate+'deg)'
```

Comment: Yes ! Try to reload the answer !

Comment: this is on JS file, so I think: function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
} will not work on js file

Comment: Of course ! It'll be work ! `getRandom` function must be declared before the call of it !